# HTTP Status 400 when requesting other node js service

Tags: node.js, typescript, http, server, microservices

I have two completely separate services `Book` and `Review` written in `TypeScript`, they have separate `Database` of their own.

The `Book` service is running on `localhost:3001`
The `Review` service is running on `localhost:3000`

Problem is when I am trying to request for `reviews` of each `book` from my `Book` service it shows this bad request error,

```
status: 400
headers: connection=close
```

The code below calls the `api` of `Review` service. For now I am just trying to retrieve the body.

```
public async getAllBooks(req: Request, res: Response) {
       
        await database.query("Select * from books", {
            type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT,
            model: Book,
            mapToModel: true
        })
        .then(async (books) => {
            res.status(200).json(books);
            for(let i=0; i<books.length; i++) {
                var options = {
                    host: 'localhost',
                    port: 3000,
                    path: `/getReviewByBookId/${books[i].id}`,
                    method: 'GET'
                  };
                  
                  var req = request(options, function(res) {
                    console.log('status: ' + res.statusCode);
                    console.log('headers: ' + stringify(res.headers));
                    res.setEncoding('utf8');
                    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                      console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
                    });
                  });
                  
                  req.on('error', function(e) {
                    console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
                  });
                  
                  req.write('data\n');
                  req.write('data\n');
                  req.end();
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

The function that receives this request in the `Review` service is given below,

```
public async getReviewByBookId(req: Request, res: Response) {
        const bookId: number | string = req.params.id;

        await database.query(`Select * from reviews where bookId=${bookId}`, {
            type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT,
            model: Review,
            mapToModel: true
        })
        .then((reviews) => {
            console.log(reviews);
            res.status(200).json({reviews: reviews});
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

What I have found out is the request from `Book` service reaches the `Review` service and the above function, because the above function prints all the reviews in the `console` that it fetched according to the `bookId` it received from the request of `Book` service. But the `Review` service is not returning that result.

Most importantly both services work perfectly fine when I test using `Postman`

I have checked again and again if request uri is broken as it can cause such error as per HTTP status code definitions. But it seemed to be okay as the `Review` service is fetching data according to that request.

Also I have enabled `cors` in my `Review`service. Allowed all the `HTTP OPTIONS`.

I am using a 64 bit Kali Linux machine.

Some clue would mean great help. Thanks for your time.

Comment: are direct requests using postman/similar working ?

Comment: Yeah they work perfectly fine.

Comment: To be clear, this request works with postman but when you try it say a browser it fails?

Comment: Actually when I run from browser it just shows the books but not the review that it should also show. And I put a `console.log()` in my book service function given above to check if the request is returning any response at all... that response shows status code 400 always ... so overall I see my book service is not getting anything returned from the review service .... other than that both services work both from browser and postman .... the problem hits when I am trying to connect the book service to request the review service . And thanks for your comment :-)

Answer (score 1):

In the above code, you're sending a body with a GET request:

```js
var options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3000,
    path: `/getReviewByBookId/${books[i].id}`,
    method: 'GET' // <-- It's a GET request
};

var req = request(options, function(res) { ... });


req.write('data\n'); // <-- This writes a request body
req.write('data\n'); // <--
req.end();
```

You're not generally allowed to do that. To quote [the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1):

> A payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics; sending a payload body on a GET request might cause some existing implementations to reject the request.

It's hard to be sure from the code given here, but it's likely that that's the problem. The server receives the request, it starts processing it (running your function) and then the server receives extra unexpected data so sends a 400 and closes the connection.

You clearly don't need that data, so you should just remove those lines. If you do need to send some data with this request, you need to either include it in the request headers/URL, or change the request to a POST/PUT/etc, so you can include a request body.

(I see it's been a little while since you posted this now, but hopefully this answer is helpful for others with the same problem!)